# How to get usage statistics for Google Drive API integrated into my application

Tags: google-drive-api

We have integrated Google Drive into our Java desktop application to allow users to load files directly from their cloud drive. I am trying to figure out how to find the total number of users connecting through our application ID but can't seem to find it.

I've checked the Google Drive API console pages but the only reporting I can find is the number of times a method is called or details such as traffic by response code.

The Dropbox developer console has an Analytics page showing number of total users & new users per day.

Is there something similar to Dropbox on the Google Developer console that will let me view the total number of users connecting to their drives. I'm not looking for specific user information just total count to determine whether or not the feature is being used.

Comment: From the G Suite Admin guide, you can download a list of users in your domain. Check the [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7348070?hl=en) for more details.

Comment: This is only for GSuite users. My application is not for GSuite but uses the standard Google Drive API integration.